# Is it acceptable to generate output on my server and then output it to client's website through an 'include' with a url?

Tags: php, include, cross-domain

My client has an old domain name where his main website is hosted -- with an archaic CMS and an old version of PHP with most of extensions disabled. He has also lost access to his MySQL database and FTP server (and they can't be recovered in time).

I have access to his file system (although only through the CMS's file browser).

**I need to develop a website on the same domain name in a subdirectory.**

The website I am to develop is relatively simple, but it will require a relational database to function. As I don't have access to MySQL and the SQLite extension is missing, I've come up with a rather crazy solution. **I decided to host the script on my own website, and then `include()` it's output (through an absolute URL).**

This raises two questions:

1) Will there be any unexpected problems with this arrangements, security-wise or otherwise?

2) Is it OK to host CSS and JS on my own website and link them through absolute URLs as well? Or will this cause some trouble with the cross-server requests for some browsers?

Comment: 1. Im not sure 2. Yes, its definitely OK (if only img/CSS/JS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty slippery slope. It can be done for very simple sites, but things like sessions and cookies will mess up when you do it like this. Also things like login should be guarded carefully. As login can not be tied to the session of the actual hosting server you have to take extra care.

Including CSS and JS will not pose a problem.

Maybe a better way would be to abstract your DB interaction on your own server and write the actual website on the client's server. Next you might for example build a RESTfull application on your own server and use XML or JSON (or whatever you like) to communicate the data you want. But don't forget to do a bit of security in here as you will be creating a public interface to your DB.

Comment: Cookies/authorization won't be required. Furthermore, I could give the access to backend to the client through my own website.

Comment: In that case, as stated in the first part, you will not face very unexpected problems.